# Link to a New .aspx Page from Selected Database Entry by User

Tags: asp.net, database, visual-studio-2010, web

I am working on a website using C# in ASP.NET and have a page that contains a grid-view which displays the contents of one of the tables in my database. The fields are generic like Name, Description, Rating, ect. My question is how do you make it so that when one of the entries is clicked, it links to a new .aspx page that has all its information displayed in a nice format? An example of what I am talking about can be found at http://www.imdb.com/chart/top?ref_=nv_ch_250_4.

From my research I have found very little in the way of an answer, probably due to my inability to ask this question correctly. I assume your not suppose to physically create a new page for every new entry, because that could get crazy if you have lots of database entries coming in. Should there be one page created that auto-populates the required fields based on the specific values passed from the database entry selected, or when a user inserts a new entry into my database should I also create a new .aspx page?  This question has had me stuck for quite some time, so I would appreciate any direction you can provide!

Comment: You can also open new popup populating the details of the row. That you can achieve by adding link column and on its click you can open the page with the contents.

Comment: In the example they are all landing on the same page with different querystring value. Url rewriting is used for user friendly url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a simple hyperlink for all rows of the grid, the url of the hyperlink should contain a reference to that item like a ID or name. When the link is clicked you are passing the id to the second page in querystring. In the second page read the id(request.querystring) and display details accordingly.
>
Making the hyperlink : this is one way to do it. Add a itemtemplate column in the grid.

```
          <Columns>
             <asp:TemplateField >
                 <ItemTemplate>
                       <a href="products.aspx?ID=<%# Eval("ID") %>"> View Details </a>
                 </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
          </Columns>
```

Comment: Hey Kiran, suggested approach is not good from the SEO point of view. I am also looking for the way, similar like WordPress, how they create unique page for every post.

Answer (score 0):

Brian,

You would have ONLY ONE new page that handles all of your entries in that table. You need to create this page such that it reads a query string from the URL, say with an id that corresponds to one of the records in your grid. In your grid, construct a link per record with an appropriate id that, when your newly created page receives it via URL, it can look up that one record in the database and populate the new page.

For example, a link in one of the rows of your grid could look like this:

> /NewPage.aspx?id=123

Then, in the new page you created (NewPage.aspx) get the id that was passed and populate the page accordingly. For example:

> string id = Request.QueryString["id"];